# No error when stopping non existing service with chef

Tags: service, chef-infra, recipe

Im new to chef and trying to understand why this code does not return any error while if i do the same with 'start' i will get an error for such service does not exist.

```
service 'non-existing-service' do
    action :stop
end

# chef-apply test.rb
Recipe: (chef-apply cookbook)::(chef-apply recipe)
  * service[non-existing-service] action stop (up to date)
```

Comment: What OS and/or service provider?

Comment: i've tested it on rhel6 with initd and on rhel7 with systemd.

Comment: Well, I think it is expected behaviour, at least from my point of view. When you create a chef recipe you actually state not, what you want **to do**, but in **what state the system should be**.

The stopped service does not do anything, so it's like nonexisting service.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know which plattform you are running on if you are running on Windows it should at least log
     `Chef::Log.debug "#{@new_resource} does not exist - nothing to do"`
given that you have debug as log level.

You could argue this is the wrong behaviour, but if the service dose not exist it for sure isen't running.

Source code
https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/service/windows.rb#L147

Comment: you are correct i do see this error only in debug mode but isn't make sense to show this information in the default mode?

Comment: Well, I can agree with that. I think the logging in Chef's info log is pretty sparse.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting one of the variants of the `init.d` provider, they default to getting the current status of a service by grepping the process table. Because Chef does its own idempotence checks internally before calling the provider's stop method, it would see there is no such process in the table and assume it was already stopped.

Comment: i thought that is the case for it's looking for the process rather than the service itself. but how would someone validate that the recipe is correct when running on version distribution where the name of service are changes.

Comment: With systemd, you should get an error from systemctl when you try to get the status of an unknown unit I think. With the initd provider(s) you can set `supports status: true` to make it use `/etc/init.d/name status` to get the status instead of the pgrep, that would make it error.

Comment: i tried that in rhel6 and rhel7 both the same result. (no error)

Comment: Are you using just action stop or '['stop', 'disable']'?